# R - keep random rows per group, but different numbers per group

Tags: r, random, group-by, dplyr

The function *sample_n()* from package **dplyr** allows to randomly keep a specific number of rows. Combine with *group_by()*, you can for instance keep 2 observations per group:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(vs, drat) %>% 
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  sample_n(2)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   vs [2]
     vs  drat
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0  3.07
2     0  3.9 
3     1  4.22
4     1  3.08
```

***Question*:** is there an easy way to select a different number of observations per group? For instance, if I want to keep 2 observations for the first group, and 3 for the second one. If I give a vector to the function *sample_n()*, it only uses the first value (result is the same as above).

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(vs, drat) %>% 
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  sample_n(c(2,3))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create list-columns of each groups using group_nest(), add a column with the number of samples you want in each group,  then map these two columns to the sample_n() function:

```
library(tidyverse)



mtcars %>% 
  select(vs, drat) %>% 
  group_nest(vs, keep= TRUE)  %>%
  add_column(mysamples = c(2,3)) %>% 
  mutate(sampled  = map2(data , mysamples, ~ sample_n(.x, .y))) %>%
  .$sampled %>%
  bind_rows()


# A tibble: 5 x 2
     vs  drat
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0  3.15
2     0  4.22
3     1  3.7 
4     1  4.93
5     1  3.08
>
```